# Could not get unknown property 'cppFlags' for object of type

Tags: gradle, android-ndk

I am moving a project from an older Gradle version where it worked fine to the current and have just been running into one issue after another. Most I have googled but have just hit a wall on this one.

```
Error:(20, 0) Could not get unknown property 'cppFlags' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.NdkOptions.
```

It is the `cppFlag.add`  section below for NDK

I have a feeling it has something to do with NDK or CMake or something like that however I'm stumped and not really a Gradle guy. 
I have not posted the application gradle only because it is fairly large but can do if needed.

Would greatly appreciate some help on this. 
Thanks

Module Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

def basedir = projectDir.absolutePath

android {
    compileSdkVersion=26
    buildToolsVersion="27.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        ndk {
            moduleName "biocore"
                stl = "gnustl_shared"

                cppFlags.add("-std=c++11")
                cppFlags.add("-frtti")
                cppFlags.add("-fexceptions")

                cppFlags.add("-I${basedir}/src/main/headers".toString())
                cppFlags.add("-iquote${basedir}/src/main/jni".toString())

                ldLibs.addAll(["android","log","atomic","z"])
        }
    }

}

android.productFlavors {
    create("armv7") {
        ndk.abiFilters.add("armeabi-v7a")
        String libsDir = "${basedir}/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/"
        ndk.ldLibs.addAll([
                libsDir + "libopencv_legacy.a",
                libsDir + "libopencv_calib3d.a",
                libsDir + "libopencv_features2d.a",
                libsDir + "libopencv_flann.a",
                libsDir + "libopencv_imgproc.a",
                libsDir + "libopencv_highgui.a",
                libsDir + "libopencv_contrib.a",
                libsDir + "libopencv_objdetect.a",
                libsDir + "libopencv_core.a",
                libsDir + "libtbb.a",
                libsDir + "liblibtiff.a",
                libsDir + "liblibpng.a",
                libsDir + "liblibjpeg.a",
                libsDir + "liblibjasper.a",
                libsDir + "libIlmImf.a",
        ])
    }
}

android.compileOptions.with {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

android.dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
}
```

Project Gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
 // classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.11.1'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
 }
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
    google()
 }
}
```

**UPDATE**
Per Michaels suggestion (if I understand it correctly) I altered as follows ;

```
  ndk {
           moduleName "biocore"
           stl="gnustl_shared"

       }
        externalNativeBuild{
            cmake {
                cppFlags.add("-std=c++11")
                cppFlags.add("-frtti")
                cppFlags.add("-fexceptions")

                cppFlags.add("-I${basedir}/src/main/headers".toString())
                cppFlags.add("-iquote${basedir}/src/main/jni".toString())

               ldLibs.addAll(["android", "log", "atomic", "z"])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I am seeing a similar issue - unknown property 'ldLibs'
I tried moving that line to the ndk{  block but get the same message. 
If I comment it out ( ldLids.addAll ) it then falls over in the productFlavors block at  ndk.abiFilters with that same message - unknown property

Comment: Perhaps you meant to use `cppFlags` in `android { defaultConfig { externalNativeBuild { cmake {} } } }`?

Comment: @Michael thanks just tried that. There seemed to be some forward movement. It now passes the cppFlags code but falls over with a similar issue - unknown property - ldLibs. I added the code above.

Comment: There's no such property in `externalNativeBuild { cmake {} }`. AFAIK you're supposed to specify libraries to link against using `target_link_libraries` in your CMakeLists.txt.

Answer (score 0):

With help from @Michael I have it sorted.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            cppFlags "-fexceptions"
        }
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"
        }
    }
    debug {
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"
        }
    }
}

externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path "CMakeLists.txt"
    }
}

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Comment: I would recommend to move the `-fexceptions` flag to **CMakeLists.txt**. Note that this flag may be relevant not only for C++, but for C compiler, too (if your project has or will have C files).

Answer (score 0):

You started with the *experimental* gradle plugin. This was meant to provide build settings for C++ libraries in gradle. This plugin [is facing end-of-life](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental) (see teh link for detailed excuses). These days, Google provides [external native build tools](https://d.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html) instead, and they recommend **cmake** over **ndkBuild**.

This means that all flags and configurations should be handled in **CMakeLists.txt**, with exception of [very few parameters](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ExternalNativeNdkBuildOptions.html) that can fine tune the build for different flavors, or gradle configuration.